# Why don’t some SaaS buy buttons go to checkout?

Tags: user-expectation, checkout, cta

I’m seeing a trend when looking at pricing pages for online saas applications. When you see a tier with the price and features you want you can hit the “purchase” call to action button. But, instead of taking my money they guide me through signing up for the free trial version. Why is this pattern so common? To me, it seems if I’ve committed to pushing that button I’m ready to give you money. Why derail that process?

Examples:
Clickup.com
Monday.com
Asana.com (has a small link below the button to actually purchases it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's no downside in doing this.** Consider these three scenarios:

**1. You know you want the product and are willing to pay for it.** By starting the free trial, you get to start using the product you want and don't have to pay for it yet. Customer delight!

**2. You think you might want the product but you don't know if you're willing to pay for it yet**. The SAAS company hopes that by using it, you'll understand its value in depth, develop it as a habit, and decide to pay for it when the trial ends.

**3. You use the product during the free trial period and decide that you don't want it**. At least your credit card wasn't charged and you don't have to request a refund, which costs the company money.

If there's a situation where you *must* make your first payment on or by a certain day (and those scenarios exist, especially when working with procurement department rules), you can click the little link that lets you go right into it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! I guess I still fundamentally don’t see the point if the buy button is right next to a free trial tier. If they wanted the no commitment they’d pick that one. If they’re ready to buy they’d click “buy”.